# drawImage onto Canvas - Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, svg

I had problem with convert svg to png. I used drawImage on Canvas.
Code:

```
ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, String(canv.width), String(canv.height));
ctx.fillStyle = "#435a6b";
ctx.font = "15px Georgia";

$.each(svgs, function (k, v) {
    var svgURL = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgs[k]);
    img  = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        if (subprocesses[k].name == '_main') {
            ctx.fillText(workflowname, 10, offSetHeigth + 15);
        } else {
            ctx.fillText("Podproces: " + subprocesses[k].label, 10, offSetHeigth + 15 );
        }
        offSetHeigth = offSetHeigth + 15;
        var height = svgs[iterator].style.minHeight.replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, offSetHeigth);
        var images = svgs[iterator].querySelectorAll('image');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var imgs = new Image();
            imgs.src = images[i].href.baseVal;
            ctx.drawImage(imgs, images[i].x.baseVal.value, images[i].y.baseVal.value + offSetHeigth, images[i].width.baseVal.value, images[i].height.baseVal.value);
        }
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        iterator++;
        if (iterator == svgs.length) {
            link.href = canv.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
            link.download = workflowname + ".png";
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            $.ithrobber.hide_throbber();
            link.remove();
            $.each(svgs, function (k, v) {
                svgs[k].remove();
            });
        }
        offSetHeigth = offSetHeigth + Number(height);
    };
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgURL);
```

Exported image (Firefox): [image]

Chrome:[image]

Under image in chrome is "not loaded img". Two months ago om chrome worked good.

If i comment `ctx.drawImage(imgs, images[i].x.baseVal.value, images[i].y.baseVal.value...`
then:
[image: Chrome]

Comment: Report a bug to Chrome's bugtracker if it used to work. There's nothing much to be achieved by a question here.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var imgs = new Image();
            imgs.src = images[i].href.baseVal;
            ctx.drawImage(imgs, ...
        }` You are running into problems here. The loading of your images is asynchronous. At the time you call `drawImage`, it would probably not have loaded yet, even if cached. You must listen to their onload event listener.

Comment: No, if i comment this, i had last PNG. And this code in chrome work in december